# What is the difference between find command options- -atime & -mtime?

Tags: unix

I cannot understand the difference between -atime & -mtime options of 'find' command. The man page gives the same definition for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
atime is the file access time.  
mtime is the file modify time.
```

there is also `ctime`

ctime and mtime will be the same, unless only the file attributes (like ownership) are updated. In that case only the ctime gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux/unix file system,

Files having three times. That is access, modified and change time.
There is a difference between the access and modified time.

Access time is last access of the file.

Modified time is Last modification done in that file.

Change time is last modification done in the file attributes like changing mode and ownership of that file.

```
-atime: It gives the result with the access time of that file or folder.

-mtime: It gives the result with the modified time of that file or folder.
```

Comment: Yes! I got my answer. Thank you Karthikeyan.